# Numeric Field types when creating access db with ADOX give me COMExceptions

Tags: c#, ms-access, com, adox

I'm trying to create Access DB using ADOX namespace...

Everything worked fine when I was defining all the fields as *ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar* for test purpose, but now I'm trying to define
integer or decimal (numeric types) and my code doesn't work anymore...

Exceptions I got are a vicious circle.

adInteger throws Invalid type exception,
adDecimal throws Invalid type exception,
adNumeric throw Invalid precision exception

I can't find single source of correct way of defning numeric fields!

```
ADOX.Table table1 = new ADOX.Table();
        ADOX.Key tableKey1 = new Key();
        ADOX.Column idColumn1 = new Column();
        // Define column with AutoIncrement features
        idColumn1.Name = "ID";
        idColumn1.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;
        // Set ID as primary key
        tableKey1.Name = "Primary Key";
        tableKey1.Columns.Append("ID");
        tableKey1.Type = KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary;
        //Create the table and it's fields. 
        table1.Name = "Artikli";
        table1.Columns.Append(idColumn1);
        table1.Columns.Append("FLAG", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
        table1.Columns.Append("SIFRA", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
        table1.Columns.Append("BARKOD", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
        table1.Columns.Append("NAZIV", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
        table1.Columns.Append("JM", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
        table1.Columns.Append("TB", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adNumeric);
        table1.Columns.Append("MPC", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adNumeric);
        table1.Columns.Append("VPC", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adNumeric);
        table1.Columns.Append("NC", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adNumeric);
        table1.Columns.Append("ZALIHE", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
        table1.Columns.Append("RG", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
        table1.Columns.Append("KALO", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);


cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

            // Must create database file before applying autonumber to column
            idColumn.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn1.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn1.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn2.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn2.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn3.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn3.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn4.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn4.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn5.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn5.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn6.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn6.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn7.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn7.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            idColumn8.ParentCatalog = cat;
            idColumn8.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;

            cat.Tables.Append(table);
            cat.Tables.Append(table1); // throws exception
            cat.Tables.Append(table2);
            cat.Tables.Append(table3);
            cat.Tables.Append(table4);
            cat.Tables.Append(table5);
            cat.Tables.Append(table6);
            cat.Tables.Append(table7);
            cat.Tables.Append(table8);
```

Comment: OK I found this info: * When you use the adNumeric data type with Microsoft Jet 4.0 and Microsoft SQL Server 7.0, you must set precision... working on how to set precision now - I will post update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I have to define precision for numeric type...
this is the syntax but if anybody knows simpler syntax please share.

```
ADOX.Column numeric = new Column();
        numeric.Name = "TB";
        numeric.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adNumeric;
        numeric.Precision = 17;

table1.Columns.Append(numeric);
```